# Drawing a 'turning wheel' using Core Graphics?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

Can someone provide an example of drawing an *iPhone-like* turning wheel using **Core Graphics**. I know it can be done by drawing a sequence of lines but that requires a *math formula* to work out line points. **Can someone help me with that?**

Here is how it should look like:

[image]

It looks like it is made up of several lines with rounded edges and a circle drawn in the middle. Drawing the lines requires sophisticated maths.

Comment: Vague tags, I have no idea what you are dealing with? Guess Win Mobile 6?

Comment: Uh, I guess there are LOTS of platforms which use Objective-C and which have Core Graphics. Oh wait, there are only two.

Comment: Ever thought leppie might not know that?

Comment: Ok, I apologize, but I thought everyone knew that Objective-C was a language native to MacOS X and it's derivatives. (and NeXTStep which is dead)

Comment: It is possible that leppie doesn't know that Objective-c is used nowadays to create Mac OS X applications, and that Core Graphics is part of Mac OS X frameworks; saying that the question is too vague is not exact, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That requires no sophisticated maths, only simple geometry. The points on a circle are described with the equations

```
 x = r * cos a
 y = r * sin a
```

for the radius `r` and any angle `a` from 0 to 2π.

You can figure out the angles by dividing the whole circle (2π) by the number of lines you need. With that info you can calculate the start- and end points of the lines and draw them.

But it's probably better to use the system-provided progress indicator or store the animation frames as images and draw those instead of relying on code to do all the drawing.